# Highcharts: Misaligned points and ticks with multiple series

Tags: highcharts

I'm frustrated because after hours of trying I couldn't find the solution:
Somehow all my series (AND the xaxis) aren't correctly aligned. E.g. two points with different (!) timestamps are aligned directly above eachother and the timestamp on the x-axis also doesn't match (Pictures: [Pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uyc12.png) , [Pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQIfP.png). Also oftentimes a point with timestamp "2016-01-01 00:00:01" is even in front of/positioned left of a point with an earlier timestamp like "2016-01-01 00:00:00".

But where is the error?! 
I already tried e.g. "categories" (see uncommented at xaxis) and putting all timestamps into an array and sorting them (see var "timestamps"), but nevertheless everythings misaligned...

Here is my code (with some comments):

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var zeit_von = "<?php echo $_GET['von']; ?>";
var zeit_bis = "<?php echo $_GET['bis']; ?>";
//alert(zeit_von);

$(function() {
 
 var TEMPAussen_arr = []; // array for timestamp and temperature of series 1
 var TEMPBuero_arr = []; // array for timestamp and temperature of series 2
  
 var timestamps = []; // all timestamps of all series
  
  $.when(
 
                // php correctly returns a JSON filled with multiple  arrays like ['2016-01-01 00:00:00', '0.00'] which are all in correct order
  $.get('values_aussen.php', {von: zeit_von, bis: zeit_bis}, function(data) {
   
   var result = JSON.parse(data);
   
   for (var key in result) {
     TEMPAussen_arr.push([key, parseFloat(result[key])]);
     timestamps.push(key);
   }
 
  }),
  // php correctly returns a JSON filled with multiple arrays like ['2016-01-01 00:00:00', '0.00'] which are all in correct order
  $.get('values_buero.php', {von: zeit_von, bis: zeit_bis}, function(data) {
   
   var result = JSON.parse(data);
   for (var key in result) {
     TEMPBuero_arr.push([key, parseFloat(result[key])]);
     timestamps.push(key);
   }
   
   
  
  })
 
 ).then(function() {
  
        // All timestamps are correctly sorted (working!)
  timestamps.sort(function(x, y){
       return y > x ? -1 : 1;
  });
  

        $('#chart7').highcharts({
            chart : {
    renderTo: 'spline',
    animation: true,
          width: $(this).parent().width(),
    zoomType: 'xy',
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(45,50,55,1.00)',
    reflow: true

            },
 legend : {
    itemStyle: {
     
                  font: '14pt Helvetica',
     color: 'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)'
    },
    itemHoverStyle: {
     color: 'rgba(221,121,121,1.00)'
    },
    verticalAlign: 'bottom',
    align: 'center',
    //x: -30
   },
            subtitle : {
                text : '',
            style: { 
      color: 'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)'
     },
     align: 'left'
            },
            xAxis : {
  tickPositioner: function(min, max) {
                   return timestamps;
                },
  type: 'datetime',
                //categories: timestamps,
                title : {
                    text : '',
     style: {
      color: 'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)'
     }
                },
    labels: {
                style: {
                    color: 'white',
                    fontSize:'8pt'
                 }
             }
 
    
            },
            yAxis : {
                title : {
                    text : '',
     style: { 
      color: 'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)'
     }
                },
                labels : {
                    formatter : function() {
                        return this.value;
                    },
   style: { 
      color: 'rgba(255,255,255,1.00)'
     }
                }
            },
            tooltip : {
    enabled: true,
                crosshairs : true,
                shared : false,
                valueSuffix : ''
            },
            plotOptions : {
                spline : {
                    marker : {
                        radius : 2,
                        //lineColor : '#000000',
                        lineWidth : 0
                    }
                }
            },
            series : [{
     turboThreshold: 0, 
                name : 'Aussen',
                data : TEMPAussen_arr,
    color: '#FF6666'
            },
   {
     turboThreshold: 0,
                name : 'Büro',
                data : TEMPBuero_arr,
    color: '#99AAFF'
    //color: '#FF0000'
            }
   
   ],
   credits: {
         enabled: false
     },
   
   global: { 
    useUTC: false 
   }
   
        });

});
 
});
 
</script>
```

Comment: Going to need a live example demonstrating the problem. What do your finished `timestamps`, `TEMPAussen_arr`, and `TEMPBuero_arr` arrays look like?

Comment: TEMPAussen_arr and TEMPBuero_arr booth look like this: [['2016-01-01 00:00:00', '30.00'], ['2016-01-01 00:01:23', '-12.00'], ... ]. So basically 2D-Arrays (containing timestamp and temperature) within one larger Array. And "timestamps" only contains the timestamps, so its like ['2016-01-01 00:00:00', '2016-01-01 00:01:23', ...].

Comment: Is that the actual output, or an approximation?  Those dates are not in a format that Highcharts recognizes, and those values are strings instead of numeric types, which Highcharts will also not handle properly.